# Calling An MS Access Function From VB.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

Hi I'm very new to MS Access scripting and I was wondering how to call a function. I tried it like this:

In VB.net -

```
oAccess.Run("AuditEditEnd", "zaudTmpFuelDispensed", "zaudFuelDispensed", "ID", "Nz(Me!ID, 0)", "bWasNewRecord")
```

In MS Access -

```
Function AuditEditEnd(sTable As String, sAudTmpTable As String, sAudTable As String, _
sKeyField As String, lngKeyValue As Long, bWasNewRecord As Boolean) As Boolean
```

...and it's an *"invalid function call"* sorry I don't know the exact terms to Google for this but I'll keep trying.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try without brackets:

```
AuditEditEnd "zaudTmpFuelDispensed", "zaudFuelDispensed", "ID", "Nz(Me!ID, 0)", "bWasNewRecord"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I've tried it and still no luck. Errors in reading the code. :(

Comment: @NewbieJason: Can you make a screenshot of what's happening and how? Please update your question.

Comment: Updated. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @NewbieJason: So you are trying to call an Access function from VB? I thought you are in Access and trying to call same function that you were able to successfully call from VB.

Comment: @NewbieJason: Regarding your situation, it seems that you are doing everything correctly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798099/call-vba-function-from-c-sharp. Please post other code that you have before `oAccess` statement (declaration and assignment).